# Visual Studio claims variable is not initialized, but it has been in the constructor

Tags: c#, f#

I was messing around with WPF, creating a small calculator like application. Just wanting to try F# I wrote a class to handle all the math functions, and referenced it in my WPF application. In my C# code -

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using MathLib;

namespace MathToolApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MathLib.Math tool;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.tool = new MathLib.Math();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Double a = Double.Parse(this.a.Text);
            Double b = Double.Parse(this.b.Text);

            try
            {
                switch (this.operation.Text)
                {
                    case "+": this.result.Text = this.tool.add(a, b).ToString(); break;
                    case "-": this.result.Text = this.tool.subtract(a, b).ToString(); break;
                    case "*": this.result.Text = this.tool.multiply(a, b).ToString(); break;
                    case "÷": this.result.Text = this.tool.divide(a, b).ToString(); break;
                    case "²": this.result.Text = this.tool.square(a).ToString(); break;
                    case "³": this.result.Text = this.tool.cube(a).ToString(); break;
                    case "To the power of": this.tool.toThePowerOf(a, b).ToString(); break;
                    case "++": this.result.Text = this.tool.plusplus(a).ToString(); break;
                    case "--": this.result.Text = this.tool.minusminus(a).ToString(); break;
                    default: this.result.Text = "Error."; break;
                }
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                this.result.Text = "Error.";
            }
        }

        private void operation_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string op = this.operation.Text;

            switch (op)
            {
                case "²": this.b.IsEnabled = false; break;
                case "³": this.b.IsEnabled = false; break;
                case "++": this.b.IsEnabled = false; break;
                case "--": this.b.IsEnabled = false; break;
                default: this.b.IsEnabled = true; break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio flags a warning at `private MathLib.Math tool;` claiming it is not initialized, and will be null. But if you look at my constructor, I do initialize it. Aside from this, I have tried declaring ti and initializing it in one statement like `private MathLib.Math tool = new MathLib.Math();`. I do not know what the issue is, but I fell like it might be related to my F#, so it is posted here:

```ml
namespace MathLib

type Math() = 
    member this.add(a:float, b:float) =
        a+b

    member this.subtract(a:float, b:float) =
        a-b

    member this.multiply(a:float, b:float) =
        a*b

    member this.divide(a:float, b:float) =
        a/b

    member this.square(a:float) =
        a*a

    member this.cube(a:float) =
        a*a*a

    member this.toThePowerOf(a:float, b:float) =
        a**b

    member this.plusplus(a:float) =
        let mutable count = a
        count <- count + 1.0
        count

    member this.minusminus(a:float) =
        let mutable count = a
        count <- count + 1.0
        count
```

[image: issue]

Comment: Is the warning present in build results after you build?

Comment: It is fixed now, but it built fine, but crashed when run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify it like so:

```
private MathLib.Math tool = null;
```

The warnings in Visual studio are not clever enough to find the initialization inside the constructor.

Comment: It still flags the issue.

Comment: I have saved, reopened, and even restarted VS and it does not go away.

Comment: Ok, weird after a second restart went away.